# Create matrix after aggregate a table in R

Tags: r, matrix, aggregate

I am really new at R (i've been learning it for 1 week now) and even newer at Stack Overflow. I have a doubt about how to use the aggregate function. I am trying the following code:

```
a = aggregate(dom$pesoA, 
               by = list(tipoE = addNA(dom$typeEsg), mun =dom$codMun), 
               FUN = sum, 
               na.rm=FALSE)
```

where: 
- dom$pesoA has only the values that I need to sum
- dom$typeEsg has numbers from 1 to 6 and also many NAs
- dom$codMun has municipalities codes (no NAs)

Can I transform this data frame (a) into a matrix where tipoE are the columns, mun are the rows and the sum value of dom$pesoA are the elements of my matrix (there are some missing combination of mun and tipoE)?

I dont know if you can understand my explanation, if you have any questions I will try to answer it.

[This is what my a df looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqabk.png)

Thanks in advance

TR

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example; consider making a small fake dataset.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!   Rather than an image of your data, it would be much more helpful if you provided a version that we can cut and paste into R for testing.  I see that your data.frame is big, but a sample is good. You can get a printable version by typing `dput(dom[1:15],])`

Comment: `dcast` function from `reshape2` package could help. Something on the lines of `mtcars[,c("mpg","cyl","wt")];reshape2::dcast(mtcars[,c("mpg","cyl","wt")],mpg ~cyl,sum)`. This sums the `wt` column for various combinations of `mpg` and `cyl`

Comment: You don't want na.rm=FALSE (and it's also the default and therefore superfluous.) You _do_ want the `addNA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataframe really does look like that then there is a serious mismatch between your column names and your code.

```
dom <- data.frame(tipoE=sample(c(letters[1:4],NA), 30, rep=TRUE),
mun=rep(c(3200102,3200106,3200310) , each=10),
x=runif(30, 100,200) )
dom
```

This reworking succeeds:

```
a = aggregate(dom$x, 
               by = list(tipoE = addNA(dom$tipoE), mun =dom$
               FUN = sum)
a
```

This use of `xtabs` then gives your requests:

```
> aT <- xtabs( x ~ tipoE + mun, a)
> aT
      mun
tipoE   3200102  3200106  3200310
  a    340.7700 367.1412 180.0594
  b    280.9851 485.8780 798.4880
  c    280.7682 236.3637 165.2295
  d    176.6967 125.0732 132.5339
  <NA> 376.4278 117.1063 251.2514
```